# Blend vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

I believe it is a simple thing to do, but I am stuck with it. I tried many functions, but I couldn't get it.

I have two vectors with the same length that I need to blend in the following way:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
b <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6.5)
```

I need to get a vector like this:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 6.5
```

I appreciate very much your help.
All the best!

Comment: use `coalesce(b, a)`

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you very much!!!